# How to bypass input form security

Tags: javascript, events, electron

I tried to scrape a website just for learning purposes. I encountered serious form security: I tried to enter the form value using 
`element.value = "some text"`. The value appeared inside the input field but when I hit submit button it disappeared and the form got submitted with no value for the input field. My question is,
what type of security is this?
what i can do bypass it?

I tried various solutions such as using jquery to send keys and billiteRange library also tried to dispatch keyboardEvent but nothing works for me. I have been trying for the last 5 days but I've had no luck with this. Please guide me I want to do this.

Comment: If you don't tell us what website it is, how should we know what form of security it's using?

Comment: Have you considered that they don't want you to bypass it, so you shouldn't? If this is just for learning purposes, ignore this site and go to other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is (currently) no browser side security on a javascript/html level. The best thing a website can do on that level to protect a form from any injected javascript code, is to hide a key (maybe an anti-csrf key) and use it when submitting the form.

On any other case (when there is no key or when you can access and read the key) you can just re-create the hole form and submit it, or even just fake the request to the server. Thus, there is no point in developing codes to protect forms, unless you want to hide the way you generate data that you will send to the server (but, I don't consider this a protection).

In your case, it seems that the javascript code that handles the submission of the form unintentionally or intentionally blocks your attempts to submit the form. This may be due to a validation function that does not fire (most probably). For example, `onchange` event does not fire when you change the value of an input.

You can see all the events on the form and its inputs from the developer tools of your browser and figure out how the webpage handles the form, but the easiest way to fool the webpage is to fake the hole request.

Comment: Thanks can you please tell me how to see events on the form from developer console.

Comment: On a chromium based browser for example, after selecting an HTML tag (right click inspect), on the right were the CSS rules are, you can see that there are tabs. The default tab is "Styles" and that is why by default you see the CSS. If you select the "Event Listeners" tab you get a list with all the event listeners that will get triggered by that element. For each event listener you can see all the handlers. In that list there are also listeners of parent elements since many events like click, get bubbled.

Answer (score 0):

Nice Answer by GramThanos you helped me a lot it's really a nice explanation, helped me to break it.
Just 
use 
var event = new Event('eventName', {bubbles: 'true'});
element.dispatchEvent(event);